# Phone only charges on fastboot mode

Tags: fastboot, charging

I bought an used Xiaomi Poco f2. I didn't charge it until I unlocked the bootloader.

In my very first charge, it made the sounds and animations that it does when normally charging, everything normal. The problem comes after a few minutes of being plugged. The phone wasn't charging in fact it was discharging faster than when staying idle.

I tried different USB cables, different bricks, fast chargers, slow chargers, plug it in a computer but the problem remains the same: when "charging" it appears as charging but actually it discharges faster than when it stays idle or even at use.

- I never let the phone discharge to 0% battery.
- One day I put the phone on fastboot and tried to charge it.
- I leave it there until it automatically shut down (fastboot mode turned off the phone) and it charged to 60% (I used the turbo charger)

Then I thought that maybe it was a software issue so I flash it to LineageOS but the problem remains the same.

- Should I replace some hardware?
- Isn't odd that it only charges in fastboot?
- What are your thoughts?

Comment: If its brand new, then return it.  Some phones allow you to charge devices from it.  Look at the setup to see if there is a setting for it.

Comment: The battery is probably already unhealthy, thus providing an unreliable value to the sensor, and the Android apps and processes take more battery than charging speed. You might want to try replacing the battery.

Comment: @RohitGupta *used Xiaomi Poco f2* is the opposite of "brand new" ;)